# How do I define a method in a child class and return it from a method in a parent class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, visual-studio-code, inheritance, intellisense

I have the following typescript code:

```
abstract class Parent {
   static methods:Record<string,unknown>

   static returnMethods () {
      return this.methods
   }
}

class Child extends Parent {
   static methods = {
      foo:(foo:string) => {
         return 'foo ' + foo
      }
   }
}

const test = Child.returnMethods()
test.foo('bar')  //=> 'foo bar'
```

It works just like intended when i run it but VSCode shows me an error on the `test.foo('bar')` method

> unknown
> This expression is not callable. Type '{}' has no call
> signatures.'.

and there is no Intellisense for the return of `Child.returnMethods()`. I assume that a part of the problem is my typing of the `methods` property in the parent class.
How do I type this example the right way and so that VSCode understands it? Or is there a different way to achieve a similar behavior?

Comment: This has the feel of [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish with `methods` that you can't accomplish with `class` syntax, or interfaces, directly?

Comment: You are probably right with that. Ill ask my question differently at a later time. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript cannot assume that your `methods` property does only consist of functions. You have defined the type `unknown` which can be anything and is therefor not necessarly callable.

You could explicitly type all values in `methods` to type of function:

`static methods: Record < string, Function >`

And the full code would work now without any ts errors:

```js
abstract class Parent {
  static methods: Record < string, Function >

      static returnMethods() {
          return this.methods
      }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  static methods = {
      hello (hello: string) {
          return 'hello ' + hello
      }
  }
}

const test = Child.returnMethods()
test.hello('world') //=> 'hello world'
```

What is the idea behind having a `method` property holding all class functions? Wouldn't you be better of by then completely removing the class and only creating a `methods` object? .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've said the properties in `methods` have the type `unknown`, which isn't callable.

For that *specific* example, you can define `methods as` Record<string, (foo: string) => string>`so that TypeScript knows that the properties on`methods` are callable:

```typescript
abstract class Parent {
   static methods: Record<string, (foo: string) => string>
   // ...
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdogN4BQC5kwEAlrAgLa4QAWA9gCZgBcCASrrFZR2AHkhRq+AOYAaBAAoAZq1Y9xkqQEoEAXgB8CddL0kyFCFVoI8EAK5R8AWSZtOC7aXJfrTe-gQs1GAAdIwsHGBmCAC+JLEkKGgYAMLM1MjsCLgAHhAEbth4hAie5pZ0Ya4YOiVRXsqqSipcRlq6BqXeXjZ+CADkDf0IANQIDXXksV6x8YL4kAG4CzWp6ezBPQ7O4ZzymiR5kMEN8n0gOH3aCAD01-r9g+dQfUA)

That maintains type safety; you can't call the method with no arguments, or with a `number`, it requires a string.

You could use `Record<string, Function>` instead, which would lose type safety:

```typescript
abstract class Parent {
   static methods: Record<string, Function>
   // ...
}
// ...
test.foo()       //=> 'undefined bar' -- no type safety!
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=57&pln=19&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdogN4BQC5kwEAlrAgLa4QAWA9gCZgBcCASrrFZR2AHkhRq+AOYAaBADEArvnjVW+AHwkyFCFVoI8ERVHwBZJm04IAFAEoEpcs8NMT+BC2pgAdIxYcYDoIAL4kYSQoaBgAwszUyOwIuAAeEATW2HiEjsGUNHT+VhgAvLku5ABmrKxcNtW14pJSDiUa5RXORu4IAOQNfQgA1AgNwc5hE+HagviQnrjzZXEJ7D7dphYBnPYk6ZA+DTa9IDi9DggA9JdtfQOnUL17ixCHNfadVzftvcrsuJVJLgkg9eggALTghD4VieACeAAdcAgwMBKkw4QBCEhAA)